# Does Swift have built-in isWord function?

Tags: arrays, swift, spell-checking

I am currently able to print an `Array` of several `Strings` like:

```
["abc", "bad", "bfg", "big"]
```

I was wondering if Swift has a built-in `isWord` function that could distinguish for English words or would this require adding a `words.txt` file to the project to compare against.

Perhaps it is possible to use something like NSSpellChecker for MacOS and change ...

```
func checkSpelling(of: String, startingAt: Int) -> NSRange
```

to ...

```
func checkSpelling(of: [String], startingAt: Int) -> [String]
```

If someone here has knowledge of what I am trying to accomplish here, I would appreciate if you would share.

Comment: Xcode is an IDE for writing Swift. Asking if it has some function is like asking a type writer if it support Shakespearean sonnets.

Comment: This is interesting. The OS has a built-in spellcheck, so this functionality certainly exists to some degree or another, but I don't know of any public API that surfaces it.

Comment: The OS is independent of the language or even the frameworks. But macOS has a class called `NSSpellServer` that is likely what you're looking for. See also `NSLinguisticTagger` if you're interested in other OSes (such as iOS). To Alexander's point, this isn't part of Swift, and is completely OS-dependent. So Swift on Linux, for example, doesn't have this.

Comment: Alexander, I see your point. However, to code in Swift for iOS, you must use Xcode. Do you not? So, if Swift is in Xcode and a function is in Swift. Is not a function in Xcode? Seems logical, right?

Comment: Rob Napier, I looked over the documentation for NSLinguisticTagger for iOS and couldn't find a clear answer. Do you think perhaps I should experiment with  `enumerateTags` functions?

Answer (score 1):

In UIKit There is a class which named UITextChecker

You can reach the documentations from [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextchecker)

And for usage you can check [here](https://nshipster.com/uitextchecker/)

Comment: I appreciate the answer. Its seems like UITextChecker is the iOS version of NSSpellChecker (macOS). I'll have to do more research and play around with some code to figure this out.